# Find 10 triangles in a five pointed star using two straight lines

Tags: geometry

This puzzle consists of counting ten triangles (check three sides for each one, remember that there aren't exist triangles with more than three sides :P ) using two straight lines that cross the figure wherever you want.

You can't count a triangle that contains other triangles inside. I mean, every triangle has to have an empty area inside.
Here is an example of the game:

[image]

Is kind of easy to find nine triangles, but I only could find one solution that solves the problem. 
Good luck! Ask me if you don't understand the rules!

Comment: So you have the star (with 5 triangles) and you need to add 2 lines in a way that there will be exactly 10 triangles?

Comment: Is the star supposed to lack radial symmetry?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was starting to get disappointed, but finally I found the solution. here it is:

[image]

Comment: Congratulations! It was really hard for me... I took me two days of thinking and trying.

Comment: Have you try looking for one more solution? The guy who introduce me this puzzle said that is another.

Comment: my solution came from yours, I knew that each line must increase the number of triangles by two and both lines have should make the last triangle, and this solution came to mind. another solution? let's try ;)

Comment: Replace the lower line with a line through 9, 10, and the center pentagon which will also create four new triangles.

Comment: @RossMillikan: If I understand you correctly, that will only create three. The two straight lines don't create a new triangle since there will be four sides (the two straight lines and two original sides of the pentagon)

Comment: @justhalf:  You're right.

Comment: @MauroBilotti: I think it was the only solution. Please again with your guy. It would be great if you ask for that and post the other solution. thanks btw :)