# Does anybody know the history of this star/triangle puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, puzzle-history

Does anybody know the history of the puzzle posted by Mario Bilotti?  Who created this puzzle?  Who deserves the credit?

[Find 10 triangles in a five pointed star using two straight lines](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/find-10-triangles-in-a-five-pointed-star-using-two-straight-lines)

Comment: What is the reason you suspect the puzzle want created by the OP?

Comment: @Barker I was introduced to this puzzle ~2003.  In 2004 I programmed a version of it in Flash which I'm now porting to C# using Unity.  Since the OP, Mario Bilotti, posted in 2014, I assume it existed beforehand.  My purpose is to give appropriate credit in my new version.